# Number products of particular parameter

Tags: mysql, join, count, aggregate-functions

Hi I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `f_category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_title` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_enabled` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=24 ;

INSERT INTO `products` (`product_id`, `f_category_id`, `product_title`,
`product_enabled`) VALUES (1, 1, 'New product', 1);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_lft` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_rgt` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_depth` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

INSERT INTO `categories` (`category_id`, `category_title`, `f_parent_id`,
`category_lft`, `category_rgt`, `category_depth`, `category_enabled`) VALUES
(1, 'New category', NULL, 20, 21, 0, 1);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parameters` (
  `parameter_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parameter_title` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `parameter_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`parameter_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

INSERT INTO `parameters` (`parameter_id`, `parameter_title`, `parameter_enabled`) VALUES
(2, 'Capacity', 1),
(4, 'Interface', 1),
(5, 'Colors', 1);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parametervalues` (
  `parameterValue_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `f_parameter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parameterValue_title` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  `parameterValue_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`parameterValue_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;

INSERT INTO `parametervalues` (`parameterValue_id`, `f_parameter_id`, `parameterValue_title`, `parameterValue_enabled`) VALUES
(1, 2, '0.5 TB', 1),
(2, 2, '1 TB', 1),
(3, 4, 'USB 2.0', 1),
(4, 4, 'USB 3.0', 1),
(5, 4, 'eSata', 1),
(6, 4, 'Ultra ATA', 1),
(7, 4, 'SCSI', 1),
(8, 4, 'PCIe', 1),
(9, 5, 'White', 1),
(10, 5, 'Red', 1);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `productparametervalues` (
  `f_product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `f_parameter_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `f_parameterValue_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `productParameter_value` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`f_product_id`,`f_parameter_id`,`f_parameterValue_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=24 ;

INSERT INTO `productparametervalues` (`f_product_id`, `f_parameter_id`, `f_parameterValue_id`, `productParameter_value`) VALUES
(1, 0, 2, NULL),
(1, 0, 5, NULL);
```

And query:

```
SELECT `parametervalues`.*, (SELECT COUNT(productparametervalues.f_product_id) 
FROM `productparametervalues`
LEFT JOIN `products` ON products.product_id = productparametervalues.f_product_id
LEFT JOIN `categories` ON categories.category_id = products.f_category_id
WHERE (productparametervalues.f_parameterValue_id = parametervalues.parameterValue_id) 
AND (category_lft >= '20') AND (category_rgt <= '21') 
AND (products.product_price >= '1000') AND (products.product_price <= '1000') 
AND (products.product_enabled = 1) 
GROUP BY `productparametervalues`.`f_parameterValue_id`) AS countProducts 
FROM `parameters`
LEFT JOIN `parametervalues` ON parametervalues.f_parameter_id = parameters.parameter_id 
WHERE (parameter_id = '4') AND (parameters.parameter_enabled = 1) 
AND (parametervalues.parameterValue_enabled = 1) 
ORDER BY `parameterValue_title` ASC
```

Each product is in some category and could have some parameters (table productparametervalues). I need get list of parameters with count of products which has each parameter. After query in column 'countProducts' is always null. How I have to change it?

Comment: can you provide some data?

Comment: Oh, this correlated subquery stuff is going to get messy.

Comment: correlated subqueries is honestly a bad idea... they can make your query's execution time quadruple easily......

Comment: and this bit's obviously a nonsense "AND p.product_price >= 1000 AND p.product_price <= 1000"

Comment: and I think I'm right in saying that all of your LEFT [OUTER] JOINs are in fact INNER JOINs!

Comment: As per John Ruddell's advice, consider providing some data together with a corresponding result set.

Comment: @John Ruddell I added data. I do not other and better way then subquery, you know? It is simplifying of production example

Answer (score 0):

Not that it's necesarily what you're after, but I think that query can be rewritten as follows:

```
SELECT pv.*
     , x.ttl
  FROM parameters p 
  JOIN parametervalues pv 
    ON pv.f_parameter_id = p.parameter_id 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT ppv.f_parameterValue_id 
            , COUNT(ppv.f_product_id) ttl
         FROM productparametervalues ppv
         JOIN products p
           ON p.product_id = ppv.f_product_id
         JOIN categories c
           ON c.category_id = p.f_category_id
          AND category_lft >= 20 
          AND category_rgt <= 21
          AND p.product_price = 1000
          AND p.product_enabled = 1
        GROUP   
           BY ppv.f_parameterValue_id
     ) x
    ON x.f_parameterValue_id = pv.parameterValue_id
 WHERE parameter_id = 4
   AND p.parameter_enabled = 1
   AND pv.parameterValue_enabled = 1
 ORDER 
    BY parameterValue_title ASC;
```

Comment: It returned nothing and had returned all parameters with number of using with products